# how to convert the data stored in string to string array

Tags: java, android

I'm parsing an url using json. I'm getting the value of each tag and storing it in a string using `getString` in a `for`-loop.

What I want is to store the `String` value into a `String` array. I'm a noob as far as android development is concerned.

Below is the code:

```
JSONObject json = JsonFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.skytel.mobi/stepheniphone/iphone/stephenFlickr.json");

try {
  JSONArray boombaby=json.getJSONArray("items");

  for(int i=0;i<boombaby.length();i++) {
     JSONObject e = boombaby.getJSONObject(i);
     mTitleName=e.getString("title");
     String mTitleImage=e.getString("image");
  }
}
```

Comment: Right now you are not even storing you are creating new string every time and throwing the other one somewhere in memory until GC picks it up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a List to store your titles, and another to store your images. Or design a class holding two fields (title and image), and store instances of this class in a List:

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < boombaby.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject e = boombaby.getJSONObject(i);
    titles.add(e.getString("title"));
    images.add(e.getString("image"));
}
```

Read the [Java tutorial about collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). This is a must-know.

Comment: i stored it in arrayllist and it works fine..but what i want is to store it in string array..is it any way possible...

Comment: How about using HashMap<String,String> title can be key and value image! :)

Comment: open javadoc and read what different method a ArrayList has, you can convert into array easily by images.toArray();

Comment: @kingston: an ArrayList offers more more than a simple array. If you have a List, there's (most of the time) no reason to transform it into an array. If you really want to, just use String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); You could have found this yourself by just reading the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: the thing is i m doing lazy loading of images..i m reengineering a previously built code where a function call is of type String array..i tried to pass the function call as arraylist and this complicates the entire module and there comes a need to change the variables and function..it would be much simpler if i pass it in string array .is there any way to convert the array list into string...any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I gave you the code in my previous comment. And gave you the link to the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
String[] convert2StringArr(String str)
{
    if(str!=null&&str.length()>0)
    {
        String[] arr=new String[str.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            arr[i]=new String(str.charAt(i)+"");
        }
        return arr;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This converts a string to a string array of its characters. This won't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < boombaby.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject e = boombaby.getJSONObject(i);
    titles.add(e.getString("title"));
    images.add(e.getString("image"));
}
```

and then convert list to array:

```
String[] titleArray = (String[])titles.toArray(new titles[titles.size()]);

String[] imageArray = (String[])images.toArray(new titles[images.size()]);
```